# transforming data in R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have data that looks like this when imported;

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4
1  a    e    i    r
             j    s
             k    t
2  b    f    l    u
             m    v
             n    w
             o    x
3  c    g    p    y
4  d    h    q    z
```

and would like it to transformed so that there is one unique ID per row, IE:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
1  a    e    i    r    j    s    k    t
2  b    f    l    u    m    v    n    w    o    x
3  c    g    p    y
4  d    h    q    z
```

The data in easily digestible form:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4),
                 col1 = c('a', NA, NA, 'b', NA, NA, NA, 'c', 'd'),
                 col2 = c('e', NA, NA, 'f', NA, NA, NA, 'g', 'h'),
                 col3 = letters[9:17],
                 col4 = letters[18:26])
```

Comment: Can you provide a dput of your data? I'm not sure what to make of the values of columns 3 and 4 as is.

Answer (score 3):

With the caveat that long form is almost always more useful for cases like this, two alternatives:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4),
                 col1 = c('a', NA, NA, 'b', NA, NA, NA, 'c', 'd'),
                 col2 = c('e', NA, NA, 'f', NA, NA, NA, 'g', 'h'),
                 col3 = letters[9:17],
                 col4 = letters[18:26])

df %>% fill(ID) %>% 
    gather(var, val, -ID) %>% 
    drop_na(val) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(var = sprintf('col%02d', row_number())) %>% 
    spread(var, val)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 11
#> # Groups: ID [4]
#>      ID col01 col02 col03 col04 col05 col06 col07 col08 col09 col10
#> * <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     a     e     i     j     k     r     s     t  <NA>  <NA>
#> 2     2     b     f     l     m     n     o     u     v     w     x
#> 3     3     c     g     p     y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 4     4     d     h     q     z  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

or collapse everything to strings and separate:

```r
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-ID), as.character) %>% 
    fill(ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(lets = toString(na.omit(c(col1, col2, col3, col4)))) %>% 
    separate(lets, sprintf('col%02d', 1:10), fill = 'right')

#> # A tibble: 4 × 11
#>      ID col01 col02 col03 col04 col05 col06 col07 col08 col09 col10
#> * <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     a     e     i     j     k     r     s     t  <NA>  <NA>
#> 2     2     b     f     l     m     n     o     u     v     w     x
#> 3     3     c     g     p     y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 4     4     d     h     q     z  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Very nice. Much crisper than my solution below. I prefer the first version as it is independent of number of columns (similar to what I was aiming for).

Comment: BTW - your second solution is hard coding 10, which may not be true in the 'fuller data'. It is better to compute, as I was doing. Another reason, I like the first one.

Comment: Yeah, you could calculate the length in the `summarise` step, but it's not really worth it if you're hard-coding the input columns anyway. Another hacky workaround is to just make way more columns than you need and drop any that are entirely `NA` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = zoo::na.locf(ID)) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::gather(col, val, col1:col4) %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  arrange(ID, row, col) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(col = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('col', stringr::str_pad(col, side = 'left', pad = '0', width = 2))) %>%
  tidyr::spread(col, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr` along with some base:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- fill(df, ID, .direction = 'down')
numCols <- max(sapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) sum(!is.na(x[, -1]))))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(summarise(., l = paste(unlist(.[, -1])[!is.na(unlist(.[, -1]))], collapse = ' '))) %>%
  separate(l, into = paste0('col', 1:numCols), sep = ' ')
```

Output is as follows:

```
     ID  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9 col10
* <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     a     e     i     j     k     r     s     t  <NA>  <NA>
2     2     b     f     l     m     n     o     u     v     w     x
3     3     c     g     p     y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4     4     d     h     q     z  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R ain't half bad at times:

```
tmp <- na.omit(data.frame(id=cummax(replace(df$ID, is.na(df$ID), 0)), col=unlist(df[-1]) ))
reshape(transform(tmp, time=ave(id,id,FUN=seq_along)), direction="wide", idvar="id", sep="")

#      id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
#col11  1    a    e    i    j    k    r    s    t <NA>  <NA>
#col14  2    b    f    l    m    n    o    u    v    w     x
#col18  3    c    g    p    y <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
#col19  4    d    h    q    z <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
```